# Problem involving sequence and square roots

Tags: sequences-and-series, monotone-functions

Let us consider the sequence $(a_n)_{n \ge 1}$ such that 
$$a_n=\frac {1}{\sqrt {n^2+1}}+ \frac {1}{\sqrt {n^2+2}} + \dots +\frac {1}{\sqrt {n^2+n}}.$$ Show that for every $k \in \Bbb N, k\gt 0,$ we have  $a_n \ge a_k$, for every $n \ge k^2$.

The only method I know is computing the difference $a_{n+1}-a_n$, but I didn't get to any result.

Comment: own efforts $\quad$?

Comment: The only method I know is computing the difference $a_{n+1}-a_n$, but it doesn;t work.

Comment: can you pin down why?

Comment: Because we have some fractions with + and other with - and I can't compare them.

Comment: why not adding this to the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT

$a_n \ge \frac {n}{\sqrt {n^2+n}}$ and $a_k \le \frac {k}{\sqrt {k^2+1}}$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: All too easy (+1)

Comment: Yes, thank yo so much.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that for $k=1$ and $n=1$, $n\geq k^2$ but $a_n=a_k$ and thus $a_n>a_k$ does not hold for $k \in \Bbb N, k\gt 0$.

Comment: Just edited thanks